# username.github.io html не отображаются картинки

Tags: html, bootstrap, git, github, bootstrap4

Делаю небольшой проект для себя.Выложил его на гитхаб

https://antonnikolaevmyname.github.io/bootstrap-example/

но картинки не отображаются

ps пытался менять регистр,путь включая имя репозитория и без

https://github.com/AntonNikolaevmyname/AntonNikolaevmyname.github.io/tree/master/bootstrap-example

старые ответы на СО не помогли

пример: 112 строка и 100 в index.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
bootstrap-example\images\zmeya.jpg
```

это не правильный путь (к тому же и слэш не в ту сторону повёрнут:) ), поставьте себе IDE нормальную которая будет подсвечивать ошибки. (например WebStorm)
так будет правильно

```
./images/zmeya.jpg
```

Comment: сейчас попробую,а про слеш я прочел в комментах https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17141612/images-in-github-pages-and-relative-links